# Setting Javascript's setInterval function on a variable amount -- possible?

Tags: javascript, html, setinterval

So I'm using setInterval to incrementally change some basic HTML text on my page. For simplicity, let's say it's just a counter/blinker. Is it possible to allow for user input to adjust the speed of the setInterval value?

In the code below, playSpeed holds the value that PlayLife() will be executed at. It's defaulted to a value of 1500, but I have a construct/form on the page that allows the user to increment/decrement the speed. Unfortunately, it doesn't affect the speed. I have a hunch that its because whatever playSpeed is when setInterval is read, its final and won't change because you change playSpeed. If this is right, are there any workaround this?

Thanks!

```
var automateLife = setInterval(function(){PlayLife()}, playSpeed);
```

Comment: You can use clearInterval and replace it with a new one when playSpeed needs to change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing this is like a game-of-life game, so `setTimeout` isn't what you want. When `playSpeed` changes, you can re-make the interval like so:

```
clearInterval( automateLife );
automateLife = setInterval(function(){PlayLife()}, playSpeed);
```

it will now have the new delay. This will reset the current timer, so if an update was moments away, it will be pushed back. To "fix" that, you would need to have a faster interval and do your own timing logic (e.g. add to a `frame` variable each time, when it reaches your delay, reset it to 0 and run the logic)

Answer (score 4):

You can use `setTimeout` instead:

```
   function timer() {
       PlayLife();
       setTimeout(timer, playSpeed);
   }
```